# Displaying a message when value is not found show error message in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, error-handling

I am confusing how can I show an error message when I won't find any data

```js
const getValue = ()=>{
const error = document.getElementById('error')
const searchField = document.getElementById('searchValue')
const searchValue = searchField.value; }
```

```html
<div class="position">
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div class="input-group mb-3 w-50">
        <input type="text" id="searchValue" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Your Phone" aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="button-addon2">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" onclick="getValue()" id="button-addon2">Search</button>
    </div>
    <p class="text-center error-color" id="error"></p>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do, but we can check the length of the string in the input field to display an error message if the user hasn't entered anything.

I renamed some of your functions and tried to make the code a simple as I could to make it easy to read. There are some shortcuts that could be taken. For instance, the `clearError` function could simply be the `setError` function with a blank string and the `if/else` could be simply an `if` with a return, etc.

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  const error = document.getElementById('error');
  const searchField = document.getElementById('searchValue');
  const searchButton = document.getElementById('button-addon2');

  const clearError = () => error.innerHTML = "";

  const setError = (str) => error.innerHTML = str;

  const onSearch = () => {
    clearError();
    if (searchField.value.length < 1) {
      setError("Please enter a search term");
    } else {
      // ... do some search 
    }
  }

  searchButton.addEventListener('click', onSearch);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="position">
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div class="input-group mb-3 w-50">
      <input type="text" id="searchValue" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Your Phone" aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="button-addon2">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" onclick="" id="button-addon2">Search</button>
    </div>

  </div>
  <p class="text-center error-color" id="error"></p>
</div>
```